# Sprintf function, combine scientific notation with fixed amount of decimals PHP

Tags: php

I'm having a database table with a column called "format" in which I will put a specified Sprintf value.

If I want scientific value then I just put `'%E'` in the column. But can I combine this value with a rtrim decimal rounder? Like if for example my value is

```
$number1 = 126;
echo(sprintf('%E', $number1));
```

Instead of getting `1.260000E+2`, can I make use of a **rtrim** function to round off trailing 0 before the E, so my value becomes `1.26E+2`?

If my variable is

```
   $number1 = 12666666;
```

then I still want it to print `1.266667E+7.` Do you guys have a nice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
echo(sprintf('%E', 126));  // 1.260000E+2
echo(preg_replace('/0+E/', 'E', sprintf('%E', 126))); // 1.26E+2
echo(preg_replace('/0+E/', 'E', sprintf('%E', 12666666))); // 1.266667E+7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate what to use for the precision specifier like so:

```
$numbers = [
    -126,
    0,
    1,
    12,
    126,
    12600000,
    12666666
];

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $precision = min(6, max(0, strlen(trim($number, '-0')) - 1));
    printf("%.{$precision}E\n", $number);
}
```

Outputs:

```
-1.26E+2
0E+0
1E+0
1.2E+1
1.26E+2
1.26E+7
1.266667E+7
```